# SQL Counting many to many

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these three tables:

**Materiais**

> id_material | Material

**Documentos**

> id_documento | titulo

**Documento_Materiais** (many to many table between Post and Feature)

> documento_id | material_id

I want to fire a query that will display the only the documents that have more than 1 material and display all the materials

I tried the following code but it results in a empty table. But if I don't execute the having clause it displays all the documents whereas I only want it to display the ones with more than 1 material.

```
SELECT D.titulo as 'Titulo', M.material as 'Nr Materiais'
FROM Documentos D
INNER JOIN Documento_Materiais as DM
    ON D.id_documento = DM.documento_id
INNER JOIN Materiais as M
    ON M.id_material = DM.material_id
    group by D.titulo, M.material
having COUNT(*) > 1
```

[Results from execution without having clause](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZdJA.png)

[Results from execution with having clause](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XFbt.png)

But this one is able to properly count the number of materials each document has.

```
select D.titulo as 'Titulo', COUNT(*) as 'Nr Materiais'
from Documentos D, Materiais M, Documento_Materiais DM
where D.id_documento = DM.documento_id and M.id_material = DM.material_id
group by D.titulo
HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

[Results from second code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AaD1.png)

Comment: You will come to regret including spaces in column aliases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the materials for documents with more then one material

```
SELECT D.titulo as 'Titulo', M.material as 'Nr Materiais'
FROM Documentos D
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *,
       count(material_id) over(partition by documento_id) cnt
    FROM Documento_Materiais 
 ) as DM ON D.id_documento = DM.documento_id AND DM.cnt > 1
INNER JOIN Materiais as M
    ON M.id_material = DM.material_id
```

Comment: Thanks so much this works just like I wanted!

Comment: You may wish to accept it to show this is a solution for the problem.